# Is there a mathematical construct that expresses the change of value of a propositional variable A over time?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there a mathematical construct that expresses the change of value of a propositional variable A over time?

For example: A refers to "Man is mortal", but let's say after time x A now refers to "Some men are mortal" which are both true at their respective x value.

Is there any construct that allows to express the predicate logic and their truth value as they change over time x?

Comment: The only situation in which I can think of a proposition depending on time is something like this: let $\gamma$ be a path in $\mathbb R^2$ and let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^2$.  Then the proposition $$\gamma(t)\in A$$ depends on the time variable $t$, and the available mathematical tools to treat this are quite sufficient.

Comment: A [propositional function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_function) $A(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ where one of the arguments $x_i$ is time.